# Trim mesh/planes with another mesh. Bisect? Knife Project?

Tags: modifiers

I've been looking at different methods but nothing has worked. I need to trim the lattice of planes using the cylinder, so that the interior of the cylinder is empty. How do I do it?

[image]

Comment: The best way to do that is using the boolean modifier, but I got some artifacts with cylinder. It worked perfectly fine with cube

Comment: if you're trying to cut off the planes with the cylinder (?) it seems to work fine, at least in 2.91...